# Plot labels are outside the figure on tkinter canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to fit my plot to size of the figure, which includes labels for the x- and y-axes. The problem is that the labels are pushed outside the figure by the scaling.

[image]
[image]

Cause i am working with multiple frames alongside each other, it's important that the plot has the predefined size. I tried to make the code as short as possible, to keep only the essential of the code.

In the code there are multiple live plots in tkinter, all with there own frame, but the same class.

```
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.animation as animation
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib as plt
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
from math import *

figure_1 = Figure(figsize=(4,2.5), dpi=100)
a1 = figure_1.add_subplot(111)
figure_2 = Figure(figsize=(4,2.5), dpi=100)
a2 = figure_2.add_subplot(111)

x_value_1 =[]
y_value_1 =[]
x_value_2 =[]
y_value_2 =[]

var =tk.Tk()

def plot_1_xy(i):

     x_value_1.append(i)
     z=sin(pi*x_value_1[i]/9)
     y_value_1.append(z)

     a1.clear()
     a1.plot(x_value_1,y_value_1)
     a1.set_xlabel('X Label')
     a1.set_ylabel('Y Label')

def plot_2_xy(i):
     x_value_2.append(i)
     y_value_2. append(500*sin((1/14)*pi*i))

     a2.clear()
     a2.plot(x_value_2,y_value_2)
     a2.set_xlabel('X Label')
     a2.set_ylabel('Y Label')

class Question_online():
     def __init__(self,master):
     self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
     plot_frame(self.frame,0)
     plot_frame(self.frame,1)
     self.frame.pack()


class plot_frame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root,j=0):
        self.j = j

        self.figure_name = [figure_1,figure_2]

        self.frame = tk.Frame(root)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure_name[j], self.frame)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, 
             expand=True)

        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.frame.pack()

 c = Question_online(var)
 ani = animation.FuncAnimation(figure_1,plot_1_xy,interval=500)
 ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(figure_2,plot_2_xy,interval=500)
 var.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please specify your question? I don't get it :(

Comment: In that case, please provide an image with the actual and desired result so I don't have to run your code :) (running code from anybody is not a good idea ;) )

Comment: Thank you for posting the image, its much more clear now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call Figure's `tight_layout()` method at each figure update to ensure that your labels are displayed:

```
def plot_1_xy(i):
    x_value_1.append(i)
    z=sin(pi*x_value_1[i]/9)
    y_value_1.append(z)
    a1.clear()
    a1.plot(x_value_1,y_value_1)
    a1.set_xlabel('X Label')
    a1.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    figure_1.tight_layout()

def plot_2_xy(i):
    x_value_2.append(i)
    y_value_2. append(500*sin((1/14)*pi*i))
    a2.clear()
    a2.plot(x_value_2,y_value_2)
    a2.set_xlabel('X Label')
    a2.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    figure_2.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a lot easier than i expected